# Session getting expired while php script is running

Tags: php, mysql, session

I wrote a PHP script in the Linux server to insert values into SQL. More than 2.5 million entries I need to insert in SQL. The script is running fine and values are inserting to my Database. But after inserting 2 million entries my session is getting expired and the script stopped executing.I am not able to insert all the entries. I tried running top command in another window but the tab which the script running is getting expired.Please suggest some solutions.

Is there any way to keep the session active until my script is running.

OS :CentOS release 5.8
PHP version : PHP 5.1.6, Zend Engine.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code? Are you sure it is session expiring and not php max_execution_time in php settings (default: 30 seconds)?

Comment: Do you control the servers where you run php and MySQL? If so, you'll need to extend your php timeout. If not (if you're using a hosting service, for example), you'll need to figure out how to insert these 2.5 megarows of data in batches of about 50K each. Shared servers have strict limits on php script timeouts and memory consumption.

Comment: @O.Jones: I tried running it by batches. Each batch has 50k entries after running that only 40k is inserting. I have one more doubt. when I did cat myfile.csv | wc -l gives output as 50k. Then that means it has 50k entries right?. when I ran the script it executed completely but it is not inserting all the entries.

Comment: @BenRoob: Yes it is session Expiring. I am not able to copy paste the code it's too long and unable to put it in the comment. I am new to stack overflow. So doesn't know much about how to copy paste sorry for that.

Comment: Sounds like 50K batches are too much for your cheezy US$5 per month hosting service. You get what you pay for. Unfortunately, it costs a lot to run a dedicated, nonshared, server. Try 20K batches. To verify insertion, check that the first and the last row of each batch actually made it into MySql.